# Format str to float and increase from 1 decimal to 2 decimal in python

Tags: python, floating-point, decimal

I have a list of prices in 1 decimal place and in string format.

I would like to convert each item into a float, change them to two decimal places and append them to a new list.

`price = ["9.8", "8.8" ,"10.9", "11.8", "13.9", "18.9"]`

`newprice = []`

I tried this code but it does not work

```
for i in range(len(price)):
      price2= float(price[i])
      price= '{0:.3g}'.format(price2)
      newprice.append(price)
```

Most instructions online teach me how to reduce to 2 decimal places, not increase to two decimal places.

Comment: `[p + '0' for p in price]`?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few problems here:

- you're replacing `price` (the list) with `price` (a string) so your loop fails after one iteration
- you want the `f` format specifier to add trailing zeros

You could also make a few improvements, including not using list indexes, using more modern and Pythonic f-strings, and skipping the interim variable `price2`:

```
for i in range(len(price)):
    newprice.append(f"{float(price[i]):.2f}")
```

Or you could use a simple list expression:

```
newprice = [f"{float(n):.2f}" for n in price]
```

Comment: The second practice is better.

Answer (score 0):

`[float(i) for i in string_prices]` is a simple list comprehension that converts your strings to floats

The decimal places of a float is purely for displaying a value so converting from 1 to 2 decimals is not a thing in the language as adding trailing zeros isn't a different value.

```
string_prices = ["9.8", "8.8" ,"10.9", "11.8", "13.9", "18.9"]

prices = [float(i) for i in string_prices]

for price in prices:
    print(f"{price:.2f}")
```

Comment: Instead of making a new list with float values, simply do ```float(price):.2f```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to convert the strings to float you can do that with the method [`float()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float)
Then you add the format to the number with the method [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format)

You can try the following code:

```py
price = ["9.8", "8.8" ,"10.9", "11.8", "13.9", "18.9"]

price_f = []

for i in price:
    new_price_float=format(float(i),'.2f')
    price_f.append(new_price_float)

print(price_f)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your numbers are already strings, there's no need to convert them to `float`.  Just split at the decimal point, format the right-most piece, and join back together.

```
price_parts = price[i].split('.')
price_parts[-1] = price_parts[-1][:2].ljust(2, '0')
newprice.append('.'.join(price_parts))
```

You may want to add some checking to make sure you don't mangle a number that doesn't have a decimal point.